# Can no longer launch Bibble Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: multimedia, libraries

When trying to launch Bibble5 I get the following error message:

./bibble5: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Is this a case of another fresh install? I seem to be doing a weekly fresh install, this breaks and there never seems to be any way to fix it..

If anyone has any ideas, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely removed Bibble and re-installed.

Downloaded **libGL.so.1**:

Open terminal:

> sudo wget librarian.launchpad.net/7037027/libGL.so.1 -O libGL.so.1

Copy file to: /opt/bibble5/lib

This sorted it.

I also used the same file to sort out Google-Earth.

**Link**:

> http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/install-google-earth-on-ubuntu.html

Thanks for your help

Comment: Found link here: http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/install-google-earth-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to run something that was built against the 32-bit libraries, on a 64-bit system. You'll need to recompile the app against the 64-bit versions of the libraries, or install the 32-bit versions of some libraries as well, to be able to use it. The latter is better done on 12.04 which has much improved multiarch support, over 11.10.

Another option of course, is to re-install again, but using the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 11.10 instead of 64-bit.

Comment: Turns out a missing lib file. I downloaded libGL.so.1 (from: sudo wget http://librarian.launchpad.net/7037027/libGL.so.1 -O libGL.so.1) and placed it into the /opt/bibble5/lib ... This sorted it, I also used the same file to sort out Google-Earth. Thanks for your help